# ajax not returning value

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Here is a problem i am having.
Ajax is not willing to return me any values and display it in a message box

Here is my register.php

```
<?php
//register.php
$username   = $_POST['txtusername'];


$response= array();
$response[]= $_POST['txtusername'];
$response[]= $_POST['txtusername'];

echo json_encode($response); 

?>
```

My form is as follows

```
<div id="divregister">
    <div id="display"></div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" style='text-align: center;font-weight: bold;'>Register</td>

        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td style='text-align: right;'>First Name</td>
            <td class="registerinputfieldscolumn">
                <input value= "<?php if(isset($_POST['txtfirstname'])) {echo $_POST['txtfirstname'];} ?>" type="text" name="txtfirstname" id ="txtfirstname" ></td>
            <td class="registererrordisplay" id="registererrorfirstname"></td>
        </tr>

         <tr>
            <td style='text-align: right;'>Last Name</td>
            <td class="registerinputfieldscolumn">
                <input value= "<?php if(isset($_POST['txtlastname'])) echo $_POST['txtlastname']; ?>" type="text" name="txtlastname" id="txtlastname"></td>
            <td class="registererrordisplay" id="registererrorlastname"></td>
        </tr>

         <tr>
            <td style='text-align: right;'>E-Mail Address</td>
            <td class="registerinputfieldscolumn">
                <input value= "<?php if(isset($_POST['txtemail'])) echo $_POST['txtemail']; ?>" type="text" name="txtemail" id="txtemail"></td>
            <td class="registererrordisplay" id="registererroremail"></td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td style='text-align: right;'>Username</td>
            <td class="registerinputfieldscolumn">
                <input value= "<?php if(isset($_POST['txtusername'])) echo $_POST['txtusername']; ?>" type="text" name="txtusername" id ="txtusername"></td>
            <td class="registererrordisplay" id="registererrorusername"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style='text-align: right;'>Password</td>
            <td  class="registererrordisplay"><input type="password" name="txtpassword" id="txtpassword"></td>
            <td  id="registererrorpassword"></td>
        </tr>

         <tr>
            <td style='text-align: right;'>Confirm</td>
            <td class="registerinputfieldscolumn">
                <input type="password" name="txtconfirmpassword" id="txtconfirmpassword"></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td  id ="registerdisplay" style='text-align: right;font-size: 12px;color:red;'>dfghjkl</td>
            <td style='text-align: right;'>
                <input type='button' id ="btnregister" style='width: 60px;height:25px;margin-right:75px;' value="Register"></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is the ajax script is as follows.
Am not getting any response in the alert box.
Any help from you guy is greatly appreciated.

```
<script>

        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#btnregister").click(function(){

                  $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'register.php',
                    dataType: 'text',
                    success: function(data) {alert(data);},
                    data: {"txtusername": $("#txtusername").val()}
                });


            });


        });
</script>
```

Comment: Is the messagebox saying `undefined`? (I ask because your JS variable `sample`is `undefined)`

Comment: any errors in the console?

Comment: Probably not getting the POST.   Test changing it to: `data: {"txtusername": "foo"}`.  Like what Kim is saying... Also as stated, use firebug or other console tools to debug this...

Comment: yes it says undefined

Comment: Thanks guys, it works. I put everything in quote and now it functioning properly.

Answer (score 2):

```
 data: {txtusername: sample}
```

Where did you define that 'sample' variable? It seems that it doesn't exist so you actually send no value. Then nothing is returned, because there's no data to create response.

Comment: i didn't define any variable. i was just trying to pass a value called "sample" but apparently i should have put it in quotes. Thanks for the help thou.